# SQL Server edition for desktop application with no network

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-ce, sql-server-2016, c#-6.0

I have been tasked with building an application for a Windows laptop that engineers can take out into the field where there is no internet access. Then, they will add data through a form and once they get back and have internet access, they can then hit a "Sync" button and send the data they collected to an external SQL Server database.

The database is SQL Server 2016 and the application is going to be a C# .NET desktop application. My question is what options are available for the database when there is no internet access? I don't really want to do Excel or Access. I really like SQL Server Compact but it seems dated. Is SQL Server Compact still relevant with the latest .NET Framework or is there something newer that everyone uses?

Comment: SQL Server Compact is still relevant and very compatible with SQL Server - and supported until 2021 - and works with .NET 4.x

Comment: Are there any other applications out there so I know my options?

Comment: LocalDb is an option. It is pretty easy to use without thinking about/managing a sql instance. It can be difficult to use with multi-user scenarios though. ie configuring it to allow UserA to access UserB's localdb instance can be annoying.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx

Entity framework works well with LocalDb, you could have an entity framework code first model that auto-creates the database if it needs one, then your "sync" button could read from the database and send it to the remote database

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a ssis package that syncs data between the offline database and live database.

The ssis package can be executed either as a sql server job that runs at intervals

or

from a stored procedure . Please find the below link on how to execute a package from stored procedure.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj820152.aspx

The stored procedure can then be called from inside the application.